# Laravel: Proper way to use Where and orWhere in query

Tags: laravel-4

Currently running a query in Laravel but the expected output is not correct. So, it seems I still don't know the proper way to use `where/orwhere`. I have this two queries below;

**QUERY 1 (a)**

```
//total friends
    $user = Friend::select('friend_sender', 'friend_receiver')
                ->where('friend_sender', Input::get("user_id"))
                ->orwhere('friend_receiver', Input::get("user_id"))
                ->where('friendship_status','friends')->count();
```

**QUERY 1 (b)**

```
//total friends
    $user = Friend::select('friend_sender', 'friend_receiver')
                    ->where('friendship_status','friends')
                    ->where('friend_sender', Input::get("user_id"))
                    ->orwhere('friend_receiver', Input::get("user_id"))->count();
```

These two queries produces different results. `QUERY 1 (a)` result is `0`, which is right in my own example and `QUERY 1 (b)` result is `1` which is wrong.

Now, I assumed that other `WHEREs` should come after the `WHERE/orWHERE` statements. I wrote another query but didn't get the required result.

```
$user = Friend::select('friend_sender', 'friend_receiver')
                ->where('friend_sender',Input::get("user_id"))
                ->orwhere('friend_receiver',Input::get("user_id"))
                ->where('sender_follow', 'yes')
                ->orwhere('receiver_follow', 'yes')
                ->where('friendship_status', 'friends')->count();
```

My question is, how do I use `WHERE/orWHERE` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example from [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#advanced-wheres):

```
DB::table('users')
        ->where('name', '=', 'John')
        ->orWhere(function($query)
        {
            $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
                  ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
        })
        ->get();
```

The closure will tell: AND first, then OR condition.

Answer (score 2):

read about Operator precedence of mysql: `http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html`

in you example, the first query is same with something like:

```
select 
   columns 
from 
   table 
where
   column1 = value1 
or
   (column2 = value2 and column3 = value3)
```

while the other query is same with something like:

```
select 
   columns 
from 
   table 
where
   (column3 = value3 and column1 = value1) 
or
   column2 = value2
```

the 'AND' would be first to be evaluated by the sql thats why it yields different result